# Find the algorithm of SSL Symmetric Encryption

Tags: ssl, encryption-symmetric

Is there a way we could find what is the algorithm used to encrypt HTTPS requests between server and client after SSL handshake. looking at the network calls, server certificate or browser settings etc.

Comment: If you want to know what a specific HTTPS connection uses you have to look at the specific connection, either with some network sniffer like Wireshark or inside the client or server program: the cipher shown inside the ServerHello provides the details about the used symmetric algorithm. Looking at the certificate will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Using java you can try this.

```
    private void printSSLDetails(){

        String https_url = "https://www.google.com/";
        URL url;
        try {

            url = new URL(https_url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            //dumpl all cert info
            if(con!=null){

                try {

                    System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
                    System.out.println("Cipher Suite : " + con.getCipherSuite());
                    System.out.println("\n");

                    Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
                    for(Certificate cert : certs){
                        System.out.println("Cert Type : " + cert.getType());
                        System.out.println("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
                        System.out.println("Cert Public Key Algorithm : "
                            + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
                        System.out.println("Cert Public Key Format : "
                            + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
                        System.out.println("\n");
                   }

                } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```